# Understanding a for loop and if condition

Tags: java, for-loop

Below is come code that I am having trouble understanding. The output is 13 15 x=6. I understand how we get the number 13 because when we go through the loop the value of x is 5 and its corresponding y value is 12. So if x > 4 we then increment y which gives u the value of 13. The next number printed out then should be 14 because the next value of x is 6 and its corresponding y value is 13 so when you increment that it will be 14. However when I run the code its gives a different answer. Can anyone please help? Thanks

```
public class Output {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Output o = new Output();
    o.go();
  }


  void go() {
    int y = 7;
    for (int x = 1; x < 8; x++) {
        y++;
        if (x > 4) {
            System.out.print(++y + " ");
        }
        if (y > 14) {
            System.out.println(" x = " + x);
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}  ​
```

Comment: Your code would be *significantly* easier to read if you formatted it more carefully.

Comment: Did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: For starters `if` is not a loop...

Comment: Actually I just worked this out there myself. When x is 5 and y becomes 13, then for the next iteration x= 6 and y is immediately incremented at the start of the loop so the new value of y becomes 14 and then because 6 > 4 you increment y again which makes it 15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because ++y increments y before printing it.

y++ would do what you are expecting

Comment: In a more general sense `++y` is a prefix operation and `y++` is a postfix operation.  Prefix operations return the operand after the operator is applied, postfix returns the operand before the operator is applied.

Answer (score 0):

When entering the loop iteration where `x` is `6`, `y` is `13`, as you said.  Then `y` is immediately incremented to `14`.  `x` is greater than `4`, so `System.out.print(++y + " ");` is executed.  `++y` increments `y` to `15` before it is printed.